# What algebra of propositions will prove the obvious?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to use the algebra of propositions to prove the following.
It is obviously true but I am stumped as to what algebra of proposition to use to show a sound mathematical explanation as a proof. Any help would be much appreciated.

> $$p\land(p\to\neg q)\equiv p\land\neg q$$

Thanks!

Comment: "The algebra of propositions" is not a standard term. It sounds like it is some kind of rewriting system for propositional logic, but there are many ways of setting up such a system, and they don't have well-standardized names, so each textbook author basically selects a name out of thin air the system he chooses to present. For this reason, the name itself doesn't tell us which precise rules you have to work with. **You need to tell as part of the question** what the rules you have available are; otherwise everyone who tries to answer will be reduced to pure guesswork.

Comment: It will depend on exactly what laws you have available to use; there’s more than one set in use. One possibility is first to rewrite $p\to\neg q$ as $\neg p\lor\neg q$ and then use a distributive law. After that you need two more steps, both of which are pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, both very useful and shed some light on a new topic I am just starting to get my head around.
The logical equivalences available to be used are basically what is here:
[link](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf)
@BrianM.Scott From your first step, I then use the Distributive Law to get:
(P and not P) or (P and not Q) = (P and not Q)

How would you mathematically correctly rule out P and not P, as this is impossible? Thanks.